# jquery conflict with prototype.light

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a conflict with jquery and prototype. My fancybox don't work. If i disconnect prototype script fancybox will work. I have tried the jQuery.noConflict but it won't work for Fancybox.  I tried several options but can't get it working.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/prototype.lite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/moo.fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/moo.fx.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/image_fade.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive-tables.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function()    {
    $j(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is probably because the fancybox library is also with the ($) jquery tags. please post your error and alle the information about it

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
            $j(document).ready(function()    {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
    </script> Try this

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code in an IIFE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     (function($){ // use it securely using "$", won't conflict with other lib
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".fancybox").fancybox();
       });
     })(jQuery); // <----pass jQuery
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry none of the given answers are solving the problem.

I have another jquery no conflict on the page. That gives the date and realtime on the site. That works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $time = jQuery.noConflict();

  $time(document).ready(function() {

var currenttime = '{ACTUALDATE}';
var serverdate = new Date(currenttime);
function padlength(what){
    var output=(what.toString().length==1)? "0"+what : what;
    return output;
}
function displaytime(){
    serverdate.setSeconds(serverdate.getSeconds()+1)
    var timestring=padlength(serverdate.getHours())+":"+padlength(serverdate.getMinutes())+":"+padlength(serverdate.getSeconds());
    $time("#servertime").html(timestring);
}
setInterval(displaytime, 1000);

   });
   </script>
```